# Doubts in salah

Tags: salat, doubts, waswasa

Salam.
My issue here is I’m always having doubt in performing wudu or during salah. When ever I’m performing my wudu i have this doubt that maybe I missed some parts and during my salah i always have the doubt that maybe I didn’t recite surah al fatiha or missed ruku or sujud or i even forgot to do taleem or takbir. Sometimes I’m very sure that my salah is correct and complete but i will still have the doubt I won’t have a peace of mind until i do the salah again especially salah isha.
I won’t be able to sleep thinking my salah is incorrect and if I ignore because I’m sure it’s correct then i will start having this feeling that what if i die and my sallah is incorrect. I once googled it to see what i can do. They said to recite A’uzubillahi mina- sh-shaitani rajim أعوذ بالله من الشيطان الرجيم but still even if I recite it i still get the doubt.
So please i need your help tell me what to do. Please it is stressing me and making it hard for me to pray.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam.

Comment: What about seeking professional help?

Comment: Thank you. I will

Answer (score 2):

Don't overcomplicate wudu. In Quran it is said, "O you who have believed, when you rise to [perform] prayer, wash your faces and your forearms to the elbows and wipe over your heads and wash your feet to the ankles". So it should not be too hard to make sure that you washed your face and other parts at least once.

With Salah, Prophet gave us the best example, but in Quran we can see no obligatory number of rakats. So make sure in the beginning of prayer you have correct intentions, then follow the best example which is the example of Prophet Muhammad. Then when you have doubts simply countinue from where you think you are, and you don't have to be 100% sure. If you undeliberately miss something there is no harm.

In ayah 2:2 it is said that Quran is the guidance, so follow the guidance.

Comment: Thank you so much . This is the best answer I’ve gotten so far. May Allah bless you